# Parallel sampling and groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, random, parallel-processing, pandas-groupby

I have a large df (>=100k rows and 40 columns) that I am looking repeatedly sample and groupby. The code below works, but I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the process by parallelising any part of the process.
The df can live in shared memory, and nothing gets changed in the df, just need to return 1 or more aggregates for each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

data['variant'] = np.repeat(['A', 'B'],50)

samples_list = []
for i in tqdm(range(0,1000)):
    df = data.sample(
            frac=1, # take the same number of samples as there are rows
            replace=True, # allow the same row to be drawn multiple times
            random_state=i # set state to be i for reproduceability
            ).groupby(['variant']).agg(
                {
                    'A': 'count',
                    'B': [np.nanmean, np.sum, np.median, 'count'],
                    'C': [np.nanmean, np.sum],
                    'D': [np.sum]
                }
                )
    df['experiment'] = i
    samples_list.append( df )

# Convert to a df
samples = pd.concat(samples_list)

samples.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, you can replicate the data first, then groupby and `agg`:

```
n_exp = 10 
samples=(data.sample(n=len(data)*n_exp, replace=True, random_state=43)
             .assign(experiment=np.repeat(np.arange(n_exp), len(data)) )
             .groupby(['variant', 'experiment'])
             .agg({'A': 'count',
                   'B': [np.nanmean, np.sum, np.median, 'count'],
                   'C': [np.nanmean, np.sum],
                   'D': [np.sum]
            })         
        )
```

This is 4x faster with your sample data on my system.

Comment: This seems to be much slower when using my much larger dataset of 100000k rows and 1000 iterations. If each row is the same, then does this not sample the same values each time?

Comment: 100000k rows? Pandas is definitely not for this purpose. For 100k and 1000 iterations, the code is allocating 100M rows, groupby on that can be slow. Maybe you're better off with just the loop.